# Cache with sequelize.query

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, sequelize.js

I would like to know how can I use a cache with Sequelize?

I look at the different package ([sequelize-transparent-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-transparent-cache), ...), but the cache use with the model.

How can I use a cache with `sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM Books')` and not model?

Answer (score 0):

For example, using [Cache-Aside pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/architecture/patterns/cache-aside).

The pseudo code is as follows:

```js
async function findAllBooks() {
  let books = await cache.get('books');
  if(!books) {
    books = await sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM Books');
    await cache.set('books', books);
  }
  return books;
}
```

The `sequelize-transparent-cache` package uses the same pattern for `findByPk()` method, see the source code: https://github.com/DanielHreben/sequelize-transparent-cache/blob/master/packages/sequelize-transparent-cache/src/methods/class.js#L14